# Run RStudio in WSL - error in program format

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rstudio, vcxsrv

I'm trying to run the latest RStudio (1.2.1335) within my Ubuntu 18 WSL. I have `xfce4` running and am connected via `VcXsrv`. I Can can fire up any GUI program just fine.

So, I downloaded [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/) and installed `r-base` and `r-recommended`. I then installed the .deb via `dpkg -i rstudio-1.2.1335-amd64.deb` (alternatively `apt install ./rstudio-1.2.1335-amd64.deb`) and the install finished.

But when I try to launch RStudio either via ther terminal (xface terminal via VcXsrv) or the GUI I end up with:

> bash: /usr/bin/rstudio: Kann die Binärdatei nicht ausführen: Fehler im Format der Programmdatei

Which roughly translates to "can't run binary file - format error".

I also tried the older version `rstudio-1.1.463-i386.deb` but that won't install at all. My primary guess was that there's some 32/64-bit issue but I do have 64-bit Windows and Ubuntu and there's no 32-bit version of RStudio to try. MD5 checksum of the download is also fine. The head of the binary starts with `ELF` followed by binary data.

Output of `uname -a`:

> Linux XXX-PC 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft #1-Microsoft Mon Mar 18 12:02:00 PST 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

// edit:

When I `sudo rstudio` I get a different message:

> /usr/bin/rstudio: 2: /usr/bin/rstudio: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Comment: Similar discussion here: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3615

Answer (score 0):

## Use RStudio within Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL 2)

---

#### Does WSL 1 work?

**No**, you will get `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error` when you try to run `rstudio` command.

---

### Requirements / Limitations

#### Requirment

- Windows 10 Pro 18917 or higher (which allows WSL 2)
- [X410](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/x410/9nlp712zmn9q?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)
- [Pengwin](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/pengwin/9nv1gv1pxz6p?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)

#### Limitations

- I only tested this with [X410](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/x410/9nlp712zmn9q?activetab=pivot:overviewtab). Other x systems might work as well. However; compared to other X systems, it works very well with Hi-DPI systems, and it offers different displaying modes.
- As of now I only managed to get the GUI of RStudio running in [Pengwin](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/pengwin/9nv1gv1pxz6p?activetab=pivot:overviewtab). A Linux distro tailor-made for WSL. I tried it for Ubuntu 18.04 — But I get stuck on the Error `WebEngineContext used before QtWebEngine::initialize() or OpenGL context creation failed`

Detailed Error

```
WebEngineContext used before QtWebEngine::initialize() or OpenGL context creation failed.
Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples 0, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::DefaultSwapBehavior, swapInterval 1, colorSpace QSurfaceFormat::DefaultColorSpace,
profile  QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile)
Received signal 6
```

### WSL 2 and Pengwin Setup

1. Setup WSL 2 ([follow these steps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-install))
2. Open CMD:

   1. If you have already a distro installed you can see an list and version using `wsl -l -v`
   2. If you have already a WSL 1 distro installed, you can convert it to WSL 2: `wsl --set-version <DistroName> 2`. This will take some time.
   3. (You might get prompted to install WSL 2 Linux kernel update. Follow the link and install the msi. Redo step 2)
   4. Make WSL 2 your default: `wsl --set-default-version 2`
3. Install [Pengwin](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/pengwin/9nv1gv1pxz6p?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) from Store
4. Restart Terminal
5. After you installed Pengwin, launch it to setup your username/password
6. Launch `pengwin-setup`. Select GUI, then GUILIB from the the Menu. And wait for installation to finish
7. Reopen terminal, and reopen again if prompted

Your Distro is now using WSL 2. FYI: You can access the file system by typing `\\wsl$` in your windows explorer’s address bar

### Install R and RStudio

1. Open your WSL2-enabled Distro
2. `sudo apt update` (optional)
3. `sudo apt -y upgrade` (optional)

#### Install R

1. `sudo apt -y install r-base`
2. Verify by typing `R` in your terminal.
3. R will run an interactive session. Quite with `q()`

#### Download/Install RStudio

1. `wget https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-1.2.5033-amd64.deb`
2. `sudo apt -f install` (required to install .deb files)
3. `sudo dpkg -i rstudio-1.2.5033-amd64.deb`
4. If you get an error, try running step 2 again, and then step 3. I don’t know why, but that worked for me, after step 3 initially raised an error.

#### Install other GUI dependencies (Pengwin)

1. `sudo apt install libnss3`
2. `sudo apt install libegl1-mesa`

Restart terminal (twice, if prompted)

#### Install X410

1. Install [X410](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/x410/9nlp712zmn9q?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) from the store, then launch it.
2. Right click X410 in system tray an click:

   1. Allow Public Access
   2. Windowed Apps (optional)
   3. DPI Scaling → High Quality (optional)

#### Launch RStudio

**Open Pengin terminal and enter `rstudio`**

[Proof: RStudio in WSL 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECJiN.gif)